# Why does truffe migration command doesn't work ? for me

Tags: ethereum, solidity, truffle, ganache

```
Could not connect to your Ethereum client with the following parameters: - host > 127.0.0.1 - port > 7545 - network_id > * Please check that your Ethereum client: - is running - is accepting RPC connections (i.e., "--rpc" option is used in geth) - is accessible over the network - is properly configured in your Truffle configuration file (truffle-config.js)
```

Truffle v5.3.9 (core: 5.3.9) Node v16.3.0

This is from this video https://youtu.be/XLahq4qyors?t=1385

AND yes my ganache is opened , my truffle-config.json is configured properly with correct port and all tried other solutions from this work but unfortunately it did not work

My config

require('babel-polyfill');

````
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 7545,
      network_id: "*" // Match any network id
    },
  },
  contracts_directory: './src/contracts/',
  contracts_build_directory: './src/abis/',
  compilers: {
    solc: {
      optimizer: {
        enabled: true,
        runs: 200
      },
      evmVersion: "petersburg"
    }
  }
}```
````